# ASP.NET Core Restful API Communication Using Synchronous HTTP

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, microservices

I have multiple restful API components implemented using ASP.NET Core. I am not using Event Driven Design or any messaging broker service.

I want to keep it simple, so
Let's say I have 3 restful independent components (with independent ASP.NET Core Projects) that are published to the same IIS in addition to the Identity server provider:

- Navigation: that retrieve menus from its own database
- Authorization: that deals with the permissions and security
- Notifications
- Identity Server: provides Jwt access tokens for authenticated users to authorize him access the apis.

Apart from the external communication from the client to the Apis where an API Gateway should handle all client requests. There are some sort of communication that is done internally. A good example is getting menus for the user:

1. The user gets an access token after successful log in
2. Then he requests the menus he can view, so a request is forwarded to Navigation API
3. Navigation API issues an internal request to Authorization API in order to check what permissions the user has to limit his access to certain menus.

Right Now, I am managing the communication by a common library called Service Proxies, which has all the api urls hard coded in cs file (which is just for trying the concept)

```
 public static class Config
{
    public static class ServiceURLs
    {      
        public const string AuthorizationAPI ="http://localhost:port/api/Authorization/" ; 

    }
}


    public class AuthorizationServiceProxy : IAuthorizationServiceProxy
    {
     //ServiceProxy is a custom class that issue http requests in order to get responses
    private ServiceProxy _serviceProxy;

    public AuthorizationServiceProxy(string accessToken)
    {      
        _serviceProxy = new ServiceProxy(Config.ServiceURLs.AuthorizationAPI, accessToken);
    }

    public async Task<List<Permission>> GetUserPermissions()
    {          
        var route = "GetUserPermissions";
        var result = await 
       _serviceProxy.GetHttpResponseContentAsType<List<Permission>>(route);

        return result;
    }
```

AuthorizationProxy and all proxies will be just to issue a request from an API to another one.

How would an interprocess communication would be handled in my case?

Comment: Did you try http://github.com/rogeralsing/Microphone ?

Comment: Not Yet, I will give it a try, any other recommendations?

Comment: Other then service fabric, , nope. Service Fabric is different, you can use reliable services/reliable actors in a similar fashion to microphone (or zookeeper in the java world), but persistence is quite different